# Read from video capture device deadlock

Tags: c++, c, video-streaming, capture

I want capture image frame from video capture device on win7
and directly work with the RGB data.
The code is working but when device is off application is stuck.
I can't kill process. There are 2 devices to select webcam or a video 
capture device. With capDlgVideoSource sometimes a dialog opens and I can select one.

How to avoid a deadlock when device is off ?
How to put video frame data direcly in memory instead to a file ? 
Solved with frame copy to clipboard and then copy to memory
How can I explicitly set a device ?
The microsoft documentation is so less.
capDriverConnect(hCam, X)  with X=1,2,3 doesnt work. 0 is right.
It seems "0" addresses both devices. 
capDlgVideoSource(hCam); let me sometimes choose a driver in a dialog
sometimes not.
Sometimes without having asked for it mysteriously dialog pops up for selecting device sometimes not.

Please, can anybody help me to fix this unclear behaviour.

```
  // create the preview window 
  HWND hCam = capCreateCaptureWindow(L"hoven", WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 0, 0, GetDesktopWindow(), 0);

  if ( hCam == NULL )
  {
    printf("capCreateCaptureWindow Error !\n");
    return -1;
  }


  // here I get deadlock
  if ( !capDriverConnect(hCam, 0) ) 
  {
    printf("capDriverConnect Error !\n");
    return -1;
  }

  capGrabFrame(hCam);
  capFileSaveDIB(hCam, L"shot.bmp"); 

  capDriverDisconnect(hCam);  

  DestroyWindow(hCam);

  return 0;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please add the tag for your programming language